# How would gravitons couple to the Stress-Energy tensor?

Tags: gravity, lagrangian-formalism, metric-tensor, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, qft-in-curved-spacetime

How would gravitons couple to the Stress-Energy tensor $T^{\mu\nu}$? How did physicists arrive at this result? I've read that it follows from the analysis of irreducible representations of the 4-dimensional Poincaré group, but is this accurate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stress-energy tensor, is up to multiplicative factors, can be defined by $\frac{\delta S}{\delta g^{\mu\nu}}$, where $S$ is the action and $g_{\mu\nu}$ is the metric. When people talk about the graviton, they talk about quantizing the metric around it's classical solution, so we consider field values $g_{\mu\nu} = g^{(c)}_{\mu\nu} + h_{\mu\nu}$, where $h$ is considered a small perturbation (there are a lot of gauge fixings left out here). In order to evaluate the action for this new field $h$, we would simply plug $g$ into the action and collect terms involving $h$, as a starting point. To lowest non-trivial order in $h$, we can Taylor expand:
$$S(g) = S(g^{(c)}) + \int\!\frac{\delta S}{\delta g^{\mu\nu}} h^{\mu\nu} + \int\!\frac{1}{2} h^{\alpha\beta} \frac{\delta^2 S}{\delta g^{\alpha\beta} \delta g^{\mu\nu}} h^{\mu\nu} + O(h^3).$$
Notice the second term is just $\int\!dx\, T_{\mu\nu} h^{\mu\nu}$, as advertised.  The third term is the kinetic term for the $h$ field, and gives a wave equation. Now, these gravitons are essentially free spin-2 particles moving in a classical GR background, with no interactions, because we have truncated the expansion at order 2. Once we try to add higher orders, however, quantum corrections require ever increasing powers of $h$ with no unique prescription to render their coefficients finite. The theory is said to be non-renormalizable.

Answer (score -3):

It is not known yet.

Gravitons are from quantum mechanics model, while stress-energy tensor is from General relativity (GR) model.

Two models are not connected until quantum gravity created.

Also, gravitons were never observed, so they are pretty hypothetical.

Simultaneously, it is known, that metric tensor is "generated" by stress-energy tensor. Metric tensor is from GR model. Also GR model contains gravitation waves.

Gravitation waves were never observed too. (Gravitation waves were never observed directly, i.e. so that they affect matter on Earth, although they were confirmed indirectly, by predicting of energy loss in rotating heavy (neutron) star systems).

If gravitons exist, they should be a quantum representation of gravitation waves. And, it is known from it, that gravitons should have spin of 2.

This is the sequence: GR -> gravitation waves -> spin of 2.

Two last parts are hypothetical.

Comment: [Gravitational waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_wave) [have been observed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PSR_B1913%2B16) and are not the same things as gravitons.

Comment: Gravitational waves were observed indirectly, by energy loss in neutron-star systems.

Comment: And the Higgs Boson was detected indirectly from its decay products, yet the results are still considered valid. I understand your point, though.

Comment: Gravitaion waves are the streams of gravitons in the same sense as electromagnetic waves are the streams of photons.

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean. FYI, I wasn't the downvoter; I just didn't understand what you meant at first.

Comment: @HDE226868 decay products allow to identify particle, while energy loss contains just a hint. Also there numerous experiments planned and ongoing, which are intended to so call DETECT gravitation waves. If they were detected, there were no need for them.

Comment: What do you mean by "there were no need for them"?

Comment: I have added a remark about indirect observations.

Comment: I meant a high importance of direct observation of gravitation waves in ground or near space detectors. Higgs is regarded as "discovered" now, while gravitation waves will be regarded this way only after registration on such detectors.

Comment: Though if gravitational waves don't exist, the results will be much more catastrophic than that would be if the higgs hadn't existed.

Comment: Probably not, because, Higgs was already found, while GW were still not. This implies that they are farer from our being :)